# Getting java.lang.NullPointerException error while running Driverscript

Tags: testng

Created DriverScript part of hybrid framework. Tried running as preliminary test using TestNG. But ended up getting below error and Failed at setUp method itself.
NullpointerException error and skipping Tests.

Below is code:

Pls help how to fix this?

public class DriverScript {

```
public static WebDriver driver;
Properties prop;
FileInputStream fis;

public DriverScript()
{
    try
    {
        prop = new Properties();
        fis = new FileInputStream("./ConfigurationFile/config.properties");
        prop.load(fis);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("File Not Found "+e.getMessage());
    }
}

@Test
public void setUp()
{
    String browser = prop.getProperty("Browser");
    if(browser.equalsIgnoreCase("chrome"))
    {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "./BrowserExe/chromedriver.exe");
        driver=new ChromeDriver();
    }
    else if(browser.equalsIgnoreCase("firefox"))
    {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "./BrowserExe/geckodriver.exe");
        driver=new FirefoxDriver();
    }
    /*else if(browser.equalsIgnoreCase("ie"))
    {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "./BrowserExe/IEDriverServer.exe");
        driver=new InternetExplorerDriver();
    }*/
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Browser Exe Not Found or Corrupted");
    }
```

}

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please post your code in DriverScript class to help fix this null pointer exception.

Comment: I have edited by adding code from the driverscript. Looks like i have added all but its skipping tests and throwing nullpointerexception error

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that could cause a NullPointerException (if it really comes from those two functions) would be that you run setup() before DriverScript(). Then prop wouldn't be initialized and cause the error when trying to do :

```
prop.getProperty("Browser");
```

Also, make sure you imported :

```
import java.lang.*;
```

If the error comes from the DriverScript function you would get the following message :

```
File Not Found java.lang.NullPointerException
```

This would mean that you wrote the wrong path while doing :

```
new FileInputStream("./ConfigurationFile/config.properties");
```

Then fis would be null and cause the error when trying to do :

```
prop.load(fis);
```

Try to use a debugger to see exactly where the error is coming from. You'll get a better idea of what the problem is